# E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. when installing python-dev

Tags: python, installation, package, apt, kali-linux

i have a problem when installing python-dev in kali linux with this code

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

but it comes with this message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-9-dev (< 9.3.0-5~) but 9.2.1-19 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-9-dev (< 9.3.0-5~) but 9.2.1-19 is to be installed
> E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Basically means that you need to install/update libgcc-9-dev (dependancy)

you can try

i have a problem when installing python-dev in kali linux with this code

```
sudo apt-get install libgcc-9-dev
```

After which you can try this again.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

I would recommend doing this if that doesnt work:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I was getting the same error, but while trying to install pip, `sudo apt install python3-pip`. I tried `sudo apt install libgcc-9-dev` but that just gave me another similar error, with a different package:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-19) but 9.3.0-22 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

So I tried `sudo apt install gcc-9-base`. Then I was able to use `sudo apt install python3-pip` and it worked. (`python3-pip` for my situation, OP can use `sudo apt-get install python-dev`)